# Is there a way to get [0:30], [1:31], [2:32], etc of a very long dataframe and turn those into rows of a different one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an extremely long dataframe (1 column, 1,000,000 rows), and I want to collate rows 1-30, 2-31, 3-32, all the way to the end, into rows of a new dataframe. I already attempted to do so with a for loop:

```
hlist = longdataframe.tolist()
i = 0
df = pd.DataFrame()
while i < len(hlist)-31:
    x = hlist[i:i+30]
    df.append([x])
    i+=1
```

However, it is very clunky and takes hours to complete. Is there a quicker way to achieve my desired outcome? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequential appends are *very* slow, it's highly encouraged to use a single [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on a list of frames.

Since [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) is iterable
(I use `Series.rolling` here because DataFrame has no `tolist` function which implies `longdataframe` is actually a `Series`) we can try a list comprehension to build out a new frame:

```
# Sample Series
input_series = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 301))
# Comprehension to build DataFrame
output_df = pd.DataFrame([subset_df.values
                          for subset_df in input_series.rolling(window=30)
                          if len(subset_df) == 30])
```

*Note:

1. `min_periods` will not work when iterating over the rolling window.
2. `DataFrame.rolling` is also iterable and could work similarly.

`output_df`:

```
       0    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
0      1    2    3    4    5    6    7  ...   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
1      2    3    4    5    6    7    8  ...   25   26   27   28   29   30   31
2      3    4    5    6    7    8    9  ...   26   27   28   29   30   31   32
3      4    5    6    7    8    9   10  ...   27   28   29   30   31   32   33
4      5    6    7    8    9   10   11  ...   28   29   30   31   32   33   34
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
266  267  268  269  270  271  272  273  ...  290  291  292  293  294  295  296
267  268  269  270  271  272  273  274  ...  291  292  293  294  295  296  297
268  269  270  271  272  273  274  275  ...  292  293  294  295  296  297  298
269  270  271  272  273  274  275  276  ...  293  294  295  296  297  298  299
270  271  272  273  274  275  276  277  ...  294  295  296  297  298  299  300
```

---

Let's look at some timing information via `%timeit`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def append_approach(s):
    s = s.tolist()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    i = 0
    while i < len(s) - 31:
        x = s[i:i + 30]
        df = df.append([x])
        i += 1
    return df


def concat_approach(s):
    return pd.DataFrame([subset_df.values
                         for subset_df in s.rolling(window=30)
                         if len(subset_df) == 30])


# Sample Series
input_series = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 10_001))
```

```
%timeit append_approach(input_series)
13.5 s ± 556 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
%timeit concat_approach(input_series)
304 ms ± 33.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Notice the `concat` approach takes 2% of the time that the `append` approach takes on a Series of 10,001 values.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a rolling window with [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

My guess is whatever you are trying to accomplish with individual data frames is best accomplished using a rolling window on one big dataframe.

Comment: thank you! but what I need is another dataframe to reference values, not do calculations on a rolling window. is there a way to append a rolling window to a new dataframe?